# Нет меню выбора Ubuntu после установки

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, partition, gparted

Здравствуйте,хотел поставить Ubuntu 16.04.2 рядом с Windows 10. Ноутбук Asus , поддерживает uefi,таблица разделов gpt.(сверил написав sudo parted --list). Но когда нажимаю F2 при загрузке компа, открывается биос.

Загрузился с флешки. Далее нажал Try Ubuntu, и открыл gparted. Но к сожалению не смог создать расширенный раздел. С диска 'D' выделил места достаточно много места. И эту область я поделил на swap,home и root ( все были primary partition) . Потом после установки вышла следующая ошибка,якобы нужно создать bios_grub.

The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for use as a "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot...........

Для этого я  сжал 2 MB места для bios_grub. Задал для нее тип ex4(наверно здесь я сильно ошибся). Потом отметил ей соответcтвующий флаг(bios_grub). Опять зашел установить. На этот раз успешно установилась,без ошибок. Попросила перезагрузиться. Флешку не снимал. Делал перезагрузку,а он опять в установку зашел. Выключил комп, и убрал флешку. Но все равно меню выбора ОС не появилась. В чем причина? Что мне следует делать чтобы решить проблему?

Comment: Но убунта запускается? Попробуйте команду sudo update-grub она должна поискать системы и настроить пункты

Comment: Ubuntu не запускается. Нету меню выбора ОС. Только можно с Live